# Bootstrap Dropdown Toggle Icon issue

Tags: plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I am using *Twitter Bootstraps* "dropdown menu" on WordPress for some widget I created and it works fine. But I want to change the icon to "minus" when it drops the content and when another "plus"-icon is clicked the "minus" should close. At the moment it will only toggle the current "plus".

```html
<div class="dropdown toggle-details">
     <img src="">
     <h3>title</h3> 
     <h4><subtitle</h4>
     <a class="dropdown-toggle my-btn" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" > 
         <li> <h6>item 1</h6></li> 
        <li><h6>item 2</h6></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

my script is

```
jQuery('a').click(function() {
jQuery(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle');
jQuery(this).find('fa-minus-circle').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle')});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dot in your jQuery, so right now jQuery is looking for an html element with tag name fa-minus-circle within the "a" element. And obviously not finding it.

```
jQuery(this).find('.fa-minus-circle').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle')...
```

actually that probably won't fix it either, because after that statement you'll end up with both classes on the i element. I guess you could work around that with css, but cleaner would be to have the "i" element default to a + icon, and then toggle a more semantic class name like "open".

So css:

```
i { /* show plus icon */ }
i.open { /* show minus icon */ }
```

And jQuery:

```
jQuery("a").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(this).find("i").toggleClass("open");
});
```

Heh - now that I just typed everything out I see what you were doing with that second statement. So yeah, you just need a dot so jquery looks for the classname not the element.